# Django 1.11 many to many does not appear in django admin

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hi i have a django model for notification which have a many-to-many relation but nothing appears in django admin ( all fields do not appear)

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    """send notification model"""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    device = models.ManyToManyField(Device, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country, null=True, blank=True)
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

[when i open django admin for this model and press add notification this is what happens (nothing appears)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rEID.png)

Country and Device Code

```
class Device(models.Model):
    """Store device related to :model:`accounts.User`."""

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='device', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    player_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Device'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Devices'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import  Notification

admin.site.register(Notification)
```

Edit:
Thank you all the problem is solved 
The problem was caused by some entries in device model that did have None in the model field so there was a problem displaying it correctly.

Comment: Could you add the code for the Device and Country models?

Comment: show your admin.py file.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2169 :

> When a class has a field that isn't shown in the admin interface but
>   must not be blank, it's impossible to add a new one. You get a cryptic
>   "Please correct the error below." message with no shown errors. The
>   error message should probably say something about a hidden field.

Now ManyToManyFields don't need null=True, try removing those statements and see if you get an improvement.

Also, try adding the Country and Device models in admin.py so admin can see them and display them.

Comment: thanks for your help , i tried you solution but nothing changed

Comment: What if you add Country and Device to the admin.py? Since you have a ManyToMany, to add those models admin probably needs to have access to these models

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models

Define an inline for the many-to-manys in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class DeviceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Notification.device.through

class CountryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Notification.country.through

class NotificationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        DeviceInline, CountryInline
    ]
    exclude = ("device", "country")
```